# How to set up ipmitool in centos for devVm?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, ipmitool

I have to setup ipmitool on my local vm for testing and learning purposes.
I followed simple steps of mentioned in the link, https://www.hugeserver.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-ipmitool-linux/

- sudo yum install ipmitool
- sudo modprobe ipmi_devintf

The first command will install ipmitool and the second command will install ipmi device drivers/interfaces.

After installing these two things I should be ready to use ipmitool. But I am getting errors whenever I try to run any ipmitool command.

```
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
```

I am stuck here. 
I have also tried to re-install OpenIpmi and also rebooted the system.
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this error comes in actual machine then the following post will give you the solution.

https://serverfault.com/questions/480371/ipmitool-cant-find-dev-ipmi0-or-dev-ipmidev-0

But In virtual machine, ipmitool commands will work straight away without these drivers. I faced same issue & worked for me without installing any drivers on my VirtualBox.